# Sitemap urlset http or https

Tags: https, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I am a Static User I write my all pages and sitemap with pure html css code, I have a question that in sitemap I am using http xmlns in order to make my sitemaps so is it allowed to add https or http is better that's why all are using it.

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
```

So in the above I would like to ask that is it allowed to use https xmlns?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to check whether or not putting `https` instead of `http` would be to try it in a browser.

I did that and they did work, so `https` is valid.  But you should note that if you try `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9`  it redirects to `https`

Comment: Thank You so much for confirmation.

Comment: The `xmlns` attribute defines the _namespace_ for the XML document. It is a URI, which just so happens to look like a URL (in this case). This doesn't really have anything to do with HTTP vs HTTPS - it really is just a _unique string_. The [Sitemap 0.9 protocol](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) defines `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9` as the namespace, so strictly speaking that is what should be used. Using `https` defines a _different_ namespace, although in reality it probably doesn't matter (but some validators do throw an error if you use an `https...` namespace).

Comment: "it redirects to `https`" - it also appends a trailing slash. (But XML parsers don't make a request to this _URI_.)